# How to type @ character in e-mails in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

quick question and story.
Someone asked me "how do you type an @ character in a mail you write in Outlook?"
For me it's second nature to press AltGR + 3 on my French Swiss keyboard. However I discovered with that users that apparently Outlook is preventing it with the CTRL + Alt + 3 Key that is more commonly known here.

Got any idea how to change this, besides training the users to use AltGR instead or Alt + 64 on the numberpad.

I was convinced that it was working until I tried today so I guess I just used the AltGR without realising. But is there a fix for this or a way to disable it?

When I press CTRL + Alt + 3 it changes the format of that line for some reason.

Comment: On my english (north america) keyboard, I just type @ and a space.  Works.

Comment: This clearly depends on the keyboard layout that you're using; I'm assuming that the person who asked you is using the same FR-CH keyboard you are. The "correct" way is to train the person to use the AltGr key - but note that some older laptops (pre-Windows 7, possibly pre-XP) only had one Alt key, so that there was no "AltGr" available on them. An alternative might be to use something like AutoHotKey to convert an improbable sequence - for example, `.at` - into the `@`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That user is indeed using a FR/CH keyboard and I don't think it's that old of a keyboard / device they are using since that would be already more than 12 year and certainly not able to run Office 365 anymore. I informed the user to use the AltGR key but for the sake of it it would be great to be able to disable that since it's certainly not only one company but whole countries that face this issue if I put that out for a scale.

Comment: Are you asking whether/how to disable Outlook's default CTRL+ALT+3 behavior? Are you saying that AltGr+3 doesn't work the same for everyone, or just that you have been made aware that a significant number of people are not aware of that key combination?

Comment: The problem that one runs into is that some languages - or some nationalities - require more characters to be easily accessible than the typical 101- or 102-key keyboard (or the compact equivalents) can provide without some sort of extra modifier key (such as AltGr). I'm sure that the AltGr method wasn't a Windows invention (I remember using it with MS-DOS), and I'm pretty sure that it wasn't a Microsoft invention, either (I seem to recall seeing it on some 3270 terminals back in the 1980s, but I won't swear to it).

Comment: Swedish keyboard; AltGr + 2 3 4 5, 7 8 9 0 produces @ £ $ €, { [ ] } also \ is behind AltGr; the two keys between 0 and BS creates \ and ± together with AltGr.

Comment: Note that Windows (and probably most other OSes) can and (internally) do distinguish between left and right shift, ctrl, and alt keys; that's how they map AltGr to Alt+Ctrl, and I _believe_ that AltGr mapping to Ctrl+Alt specifically looks to map to Ctrl+Right-Alt, and only allows for Ctrl+Left-Alt when there's only one _physical_ Alt key.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, there are different ways to type the @ character on a French keyboard, depending on your operating system and keyboard layout. Here are some possible methods:

- If you use Windows and the international keyboard layout, you can type @ by pressing Alt Gr and 2 at the same time1.
- If you use Windows and the UK extended keyboard layout, you can type @ by pressing Alt Gr and ’ at the same time2.
- If you use Windows and the French keyboard layout, you can type @ by pressing Alt and 0, then 6, then 4 on the numeric keypad3.
- If you use Mac OS, you can type @ by pressing Option and 0 at the same time4.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.